# iOS 13 Multiple file upload in background iOS via AWS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, ios13, multiple-file-upload

In one of my project I need to upload multiple images even if the app is in background. It works fine in foreground mode but in background it gets stopped after some time automatically. I have implemented all the recommendations given in AWS SDK documentation and also uploading images via OperationQueue. Please help with some demo / example source code to have exact solution.  It does not through any error the only warning I get when I put the app in background is:

**Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1fd57580, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.**

But it still upload 4-5images and then get stopped automatically.

Please find code snippet in below:

### AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import AWSS3
import BackgroundTasks

let AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "AccessKey"
let AWS_SECRET_KEY = "SecretKey"

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    var operations = [Operation]()
    //MARK: Appdelegate metthods
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let credentialProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.init(accessKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
        configuration?.maxRetryCount = 5
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
        self.doSendImages()
        return true
    }
    func doSendImages(){
        var images = [UIImage]()
        for _ in 1...100{
            images.append(UIImage.init(named: "test.jpg")!)
        }
        NetOpsQueueMgr.shared.uploadImages(imageList: images)
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("appdelegate background upload called")
        AWSS3TransferUtility.interceptApplication(application, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: identifier, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }


    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
}
```

NetOpsQueueMgr.swift

```
import UIKit

class NetOpsQueueMgr {
    static let shared = NetOpsQueueMgr()

      lazy var opsQueue :OperationQueue = {
          var queue = OperationQueue()
          queue.name = "myQueName"
          queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
          return queue
      }()

      func submitOp(netOp : NetworkOp) {
           opsQueue.addOperation(netOp)
      }

     func uploadImages(imageList : [UIImage]) {
          let imagesOp = ImagesUploadOp(imageList: imageList)
          self.submitOp(netOp: imagesOp)
      }
}
```

ImagesUploadOp.swift

```
import UIKit
import AWSS3
import BackgroundTasks
class ImagesUploadOp: NetworkOp {
    var imageList : [UIImage]

    init(imageList : [UIImage]) {
        self.imageList = imageList
    }


    override func main() {
        print( "Photos upload starting")
        if self.checkCancel() {
            return
        }
        // Pop image off front of array
        let strS3ImageName  = "img_water\(imageList.count).jpg"

        let image = imageList.remove(at: 0)
        var data : Data!
        data = (image).jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)
        let   strExtention = "JPG"

            var strContentType = "image/"+strExtention.lowercased()
            let  transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
            let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

            expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if(progress.fractionCompleted == 1.0){
                }

            })
            }
            var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?

            completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if(error == nil){
                        print("Image completed: \(strS3ImageName)")

                        if !self.isCancelled {
                            if self.imageList.count == 0 {
                                // All images done, here you could call a final completion handler or somthing.
                            } else {
                                // More images left to do, let's put another Operation on the barbie:)
                                NetOpsQueueMgr.shared.submitOp(netOp: ImagesUploadOp(imageList: self.imageList))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.complete()
                })
            }
            strContentType = "image/"+strExtention.lowercased()
            transferUtility.uploadData(data,
                                       bucket: S3BucketName,
                                       key: strS3ImageName,
                                       contentType: strContentType,
                                       expression: expression,
                                       completionHandler: completionHandler).continueOnSuccessWith {
                                        (task) -> AnyObject? in
                                        if let error = task.error {
                                            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                        }
                                        if let result = task.result {
                                            print("this is result \(result)")
                                        }
                                        if  task.isCancelled {
                                            print("task has been cancled")
                                        }

                                        return nil;
            }

    }

}
```

NetworkOp.swift

```
import UIKit

class NetworkOp: Operation {
        var isRunning = false

      override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
          get {
              return true
          }
      }

      override var isConcurrent: Bool {
          get {
              return true
          }
      }

      override var isExecuting: Bool {
          get {
              return isRunning
          }
      }

      override var isFinished: Bool {
          get {
              return !isRunning
          }
      }

      override func start() {
          if self.checkCancel() {
              return
          }
          self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
          self.isRunning = true
          self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
          main()
      }

      func complete() {
          self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
          self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
          self.isRunning = false
          self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
          self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
      }

      // Always resubmit if we get canceled before completion
      func checkCancel() -> Bool {
          if self.isCancelled {
              self.retry()
              self.complete()
          }
          return self.isCancelled
      }

      func retry() {
          // Create a new NetworkOp to match and resubmit since we can't reuse existing.
      }

      func success() {
          // Success means reset delay
      }
}
```

Regards,
Amit